# How to to retrieve the saved ALS model using Spark - Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am training an ALS model using a dataset. I am trying to save this model and later retrieve it and use it to get predictions. I can save the model but when trying to retrieve it get an error as `IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat`.

My code is as below:

```
    MatrixFactorizationModel model;
    MatrixFactorizationModel sameModel;

    int rank = 10;
    int numIterations = 10;
    model = ALS.train( JavaRDD.toRDD( ratings ), rank, numIterations, 0.01 );
    model.save( sc.sc(), "src/main/resources/UserBasedModel" );
    sameModel = MatrixFactorizationModel.load( sc.sc(), "src/main/resources/UserBasedModel" );
```

The stack trace is as below:

[image: stack trace]

How can I solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427291/illegalaccesserror-to-guavas-stopwatch-from-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-lib-inp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting Hadoop version to 2.7.2 solved the problem.

As explained in the answer for the SO question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427291/illegalaccesserror-to-guavas-stopwatch-from-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-lib-inp) the error occurs due to the mismatch in Hadoop and Guava versions. For Guava versions above 17.0, Hadoop 2.7.2 has to be used.