# Running Spark 2.2.0 with Guava > 16.0.1 throws exception

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hadoop, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I see that spark pulls Guava 16.0.1 transitively via one of it's hadoop dependencies (supposedly) but in my Maven project I also need cassandra-unit which forces Guava 21.0 which then breaks spark when I try to read a file with the `sparkSession.sparkContext.textfile` method. I was wondering if anyone else has come across a similar problem and how you've solved it? Here's the stacktrace:

```
*** RUN ABORTED ***
  java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:312)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  ...
```

UPDATE: As it's been suggested in the comments that this might be a duplicate of [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427291/illegalaccesserror-to-guavas-stopwatch-from-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-lib-inp) I did try and force versions 2.7.2 and 2.9.0 of `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` and `hadoop-common`. I don't think you can do that though as this breaks elsewhere with: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration` which is a class in a super old 1.10 version of `commons-configuration` which obviously something else relies on. It's that vicious circle...

UPDATE: Originally my code was using a library which was using `SparkContext` api to invoke the `sparkSession.sparkContext.textfile` method. The issue is no longer evident when I switch to the `SparkSession` api with `sparkSession.read`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalAccessError to guava's StopWatch from org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427291/illegalaccesserror-to-guavas-stopwatch-from-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-lib-inp)

Comment: None of the answers there did it for me unfortunately. Thanks though.

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of problems often arise...

Comment: You'll need to use mvn shading plugin

Comment: It fails when I am running the tests, so it doesn't even get to the packaging stage