# IllegalAccessError to guava's StopWatch from org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, guava

I'm trying to upgrade my project from spark 2.1.1 to 2.3.1, when I change the dependency over, I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:312)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
...
```

I've found the following question which seems to answer what is going on:
[IllegalAccessError to guava's StopWatch from org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427291/illegalaccesserror-to-guavas-stopwatch-from-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-lib-inp)

However I don't link to hadoop directly, I'm just using spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7 as my spark home.

My assumption is that in spark 2.1.1 guava was included implicitly, but it now is not, and hadoop hasn't been updated, does this mean that I now need to explicitly include guava from my project?

Answer (score 0):

Add Google's Guava dependency 15.0 in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>15.0</version>
</dependency>
```