# "java.lang.IllegalAccessError" while reading multiline json file in Spark2.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

while reading multiline json file in Spark2.0 getting exception

```
val data = spark.read
    .option("multiline",true)
    .json("C:\\user\\Spark\\DataSets\\employees_multiLine.json")
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:262)
at org.apache.spark.input.StreamFileInputFormat.setMinPartitions(PortableDataStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.BinaryFileRDD.getPartitions(BinaryFileRDD.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)

Comment: can you pls share your sample json data? I can attempt to build the solution using actual data.

Comment: From javadoc: `this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed`. If you got it at run time, maybe you has invalid library dependence tree. There is any IDE or SBT warning?

Comment: @MikhailIonkin -- By adding google guava dependency it got resolved    
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @ShantanuKher here you go with nested json                                                                 [
  {
    "name": "Nish",
    "product": "Headphone",
    "Delivery": {
      "name": "Nisha",
      "address": "Chennai",
      "mob": "1234567"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Gupta",
    "product": "T-shirt",
    "Delivery": {
      "name": "Guptans",
      "address": "Bangalore",
      "mob": "5738612"
    }
  }
]

Answer (score 2):

Updating `hadoop` to 2.7.2 or higher will resolve this.

This issue is explained here in detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/36443787